# How to reference to the top-level module in Python inside a package?

Tags: python, module, package

In the below hierachy, is there a convenient and universal way to reference to the top_package using a generic term in all .py file below? I would like to have a consistent way to import other modules, so that even when the "top_package" changes name nothing breaks.

I am not in favour of using the relative import like "..level_one_a" as relative path will be different to each python file below. I am looking for a way that:

1. Each python file can have the same import statement for the same module in the package.
2. A decoupling reference to "top_package" in any .py file inside the package, so whatever name "top_package" changes to, nothing breaks.

   ```
   top_package/
     __init__.py
     level_one_a/
       __init__.py
       my_lib.py
       level_two/
         __init__.py
         hello_world.py
     level_one_b/
       __init__.py
       my_lib.py
     main.py
   ```

Comment: Why do you want a reference to the top-level module? (Sometimes this answer reveals the real problem/solution.)

Comment: I want to make the package as reusable as possible, so that when I rename the top module, everything can still work normally without having to change each of the import name inside.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
top_package = __import__(__name__.split('.')[0])
```

The trick here is that for every module the `__name__` variable contains the full path to the module separated by dots such as, for example, `top_package.level_one_a.my_lib`. Hence, if you want to get the top package name, you just need to get the first component of the path and import it using `__import__`.

Despite the variable name used to access the package is still called `top_package`, you can rename the package and if will still work.

Comment: -1 The question requested a solution that doesn't depend on the name "top_package".

Comment: @Jon-Eric Thanks for your comment. I've fixed my answer to work regardless of the top package name.

Comment: This is not fully correct; if current module is not imported from the top level, its `__name__` will not contain the full path to this module, but only part of this, which will start from where you import this module.

Answer (score 11):

Put your package and the `main` script into an outer container directory, like this:

```
container/
    main.py
    top_package/
        __init__.py
        level_one_a/
            __init__.py
            my_lib.py
            level_two/
                __init__.py
                hello_world.py
        level_one_b/
            __init__.py
            my_lib.py
```

When `main.py` is run, its parent directory (`container`) will be automatically added to the start of `sys.path`. And since `top_package` is now in the same directory, it can be imported from anywhere within the package tree.

So `hello_world.py` could import `level_one_b/my_lib.py` like this:

```
from top_package.level_one_b import my_lib
```

No matter what the name of the container directory is, or where it is located, the imports will always work with this arrangement.

But note that, in your original example, `top_package` it could easily function as the container directory itself. All you would have to do is remove `top_package/__init__.py`, and you would be left with efectively the same arrangement.

The previous import statement would then change to:

```
from level_one_b import my_lib
```

and you would be free to rename `top_package` however you wished.

Comment: If you remove top_package/__init__.py, then level_one_a and level_one_b will be unable to import from each other.

Comment: @DonGar. Nope - it will work perfectly fine. But note that I was referring to the structure in the OPs question, not the one shown in my answer. The critical difference is the location of the `main.py` script.

Comment: The main part of your answer I agree with, but the paragraph that starts with "But note that" is what I disagree with. Unless you also mean move both level_one_a and level_one_b into a new sub-module of top_container.

Comment: @DonGar, You obviously haven't actually done any testing with real code. Everything in my answer works exactly as stated. I don't understand what your disagreement is based on.

Comment: Yes I have. In fact, I just went through the painful process of setting up a project that does not use path munging for the first time. On reflection though, the libraries can import from each other, if imported by main. But not if invoked from test programs inside the level_one modules, even if the test programs are invoked by the 'discover' mechanism. Your idea for a top level wrapper package is what finally solved my assorted import problems (I was requiring main/tests/lint to all work).

Comment: FYI this example is making use of the ["intra-package-reference"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) feature of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of the [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function and the [`__path__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories) attribute of a package.

For example, suppose you wish to import `<whatever>.level_one_a.level_two.hello_world` from somewhere else in the package. You could do something like this:

```
import os
_temp = __import__(__path__[0].split(os.sep)[0] + ".level_one_a.level_two.hello_world")
my_hello_world = _temp.level_one_a.level_two.hello_world
```

This code is independent of the name of the top level package and can be used anywhere in the package. It's also pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This works from within a library module:

```
import __main__ as main_package
TOP_PACKAGE = main_package.__package__.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe #2 is impossible without using relative imports or the named package. You have to specify what module to import either by explicitly calling its name or using a relative import. otherwise how would the interpreter know what you want?

If you make your application launcher one level above `top_level/` and have it `import top_leve`l you can then reference `top_level.*` from anywhere inside the top_level package.

(I can show you an example from software I'm working on: http://github.com/toddself/beerlog/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what works best for me with recent versions of Python (>=3.11):

```py
def program_name():
    import __main__ as main  # noqa
    if package := main.__package__:
        return package
    return Path(main.__file__).name
```