# Python and import from another package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My Python version is 3.5.

I have a project with structure like this:

```
-- test
---- __init__.py
---- one
------ __init__.py
------ first.py
---- two
------ __init__.py
------ second.py
```

Content of `first.py` file:

```
class FirstClass(object):

    def hello(self):
        return 'hello'
```

Content of `second.py` file:

```
def main():
    first = FirstClass()
    print(first.hello())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that I can't import `FirstClass` in `second.py`, I tried:

```
from test.one.first import FirstClass

Result:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "second.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test.one.first import FirstClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.one'
```

Also, I tried this approach:

```
from ..one.first import FirstClass

Result:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "second.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..one.first import FirstClass
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

So, my question is: how do to import in situations like this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706309/how-to-reference-to-the-top-level-module-in-python-inside-a-package

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

this is a hack but but would work:

```
def main():
    first = FirstClass()
    print(first.hello())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import path
    from os.path import dirname as dir

    path.append(dir(path[0]))
    __package__ = "one"
    from one.first import FirstClass
    main()
```

see: Leon's link in comment